# Suffixes for feminine professions: "-ша", "-ка", "-иха", "-ыня", "-ица"

Tags: лексикон, морфология, суффиксы

Is there actually a rule for forming feminine names of professions? I can come up with several examples (and some of the examples are colloquial, but nevertheless widespread), but I cannot figure out what the rule is.

> врач - врачиха
>   
>   дворник - дворничиха
>   
>   повар - повариха
>   
>   портной - портниха
>   
>   ветеринар - ветеринарша
>   
>   директор - директриса (or директорша)
>   
>   секретарь - секретарша
>   
>   учитель - учительница
>   
>   уборщик - уборщица
>   
>   волейболист - волейболистка
>   
>   дояр - доярка
>   
>   юннат - юннатка
>   
>   раб - рабыня
>   
>   князь - княгиня
>   
>   слуга - служанка

and

> судья
>   
>   завхоз

do not seem to change at all.

Comment: _Завхоз_ is an exception to any rules, as it's an abbreviation of *Зав* [едующий/ая] *хоз* [яйством].

Comment: Maybe, but keep in mind, there are other abbreviations that can be changed, e.g. *юннат - юннатка*

Comment: I think this is somewhat different.  In case of _юннат_, the last word of the abbreviation changes: юный натуралист vs. юная натуралистка.  So in this case *юн* [ая] *нат* [уралист] *ка*.  In case of _завхоз_, the last word doesn't change.

Comment: Some rules exist: -ист – -истка, -итель – ительница, -анин – анка... https://github.com/Pogrebnoj-Alexandroff/demonyms/blob/patch-1/-jets.tsv

Answer (score 1):

First of all, these feminine forms are not common and even rude.

1. **врачиха**: It is an informal and vulgar name of врач. Normally you would use: *Врач Ирина Ивановна.* So, using the masculine form.

   Similar for others - *Дворник К.С.Иванова*. But (this is polite and friendly): *Дворничиха Тетя Клава.*
2. **Повариха**: But *Заслуженный повар Светлана Алексеевна Огурцова.*
3. **Директор**: *Директриса.*

   **Formal**: *Личный Секретарь - Исаева*;
   **Informal**: *Его любимая секретарша.*

   *Заслуженный учитель года Ксения Петровна Пятеркина - но наша учительница Ксения Петровна.*

These words are quite old, so I don't think there are any rules for adding suffixes. Just read more books to remember them.

*ЗавХоз = Заведующий Хозяйством* - so it cannot be shorted. Судья so respected so you cannot modify it.

Comment: OK, but I'm not actually asking about usage, I'm asking about a rule that describes which suffix to add.

Comment: Plus судья doesn't change because it is a word with common gender.

Comment: Still- судья. Yes you were asking about suffixes but point of my answer to emphasize that this "feminization" strictly speaking is wrong. It cannot be ruled on 1 to 1 basis - If person woman use femine form. Everything depends on context.

Comment: OK, I don't want to start a lengthy discussion. I think that your answer contains some helpful information, but it is not the answer to my question. I will edit my post so that it is clearer what I am asking about.